# Enforcing the default value in Mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been trying to find a way to enforce the default value of a schema so that the default value is being used upon insert regardless of any input parameter. In other words a property of a schema should always have the default value and if any other parameter is being passed on insert/write that passed parameter would be ignored.

As an example, please see my dummy schema below. The property I want to enforce is `MySchema.created`, which is supposed to store the timestamp of the moment document gets created.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    sendStatus:     {
                        type: String,
                        enum: ["notsent", "sent", "failed"],
                        default: "notsent"
                    },
    created:        {
                        type: Date,
                        default: Date.now
                    },
    creator:        {
                        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                        ref: "User",
                        required: true
                    }
});
```

I did not find an answer in Mongoose documentation (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html) even though it do mention `setDefaultsOnInsert`, which sounds somewhat close. Altough I would like to do all the schema validation and enforcements on schema level to avoid development mistakes and copy-paste code. Also I don't see how I could use `setDefaultsOnInsert` for this timestamp, because I want to keep it also constant and not update it upon document update.

Is this possible to achieve? Having a reliable creation date on a document must be a very common use case, but somehow I fail to find a satisfying answer in the internet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add [Mongoose timestamps](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) to the end of your schema and it will timestamp your new/updated document

```
 var MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      sendStatus:   {
                      type: String,
                      enum: ["notsent", "sent", "failed"],
                      default: "notsent"
                    },
      creator:      {
                      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                      ref: "User",
                      required: true
                    }
                },{
      timestamps: 
                  { 
                      createdAt: 'created_at',
                      updatedAt: 'updated_at' //leave this out if of no interest 
                  }
             });
```

Comment: This seems to work and do what I wanted to do. I'm going to accept this answer even if this is only resolving my specific problem about the timestamps and not enforcing default values in general. Thank you.

Comment: I have to downvote this, because it does not answer the question.